# Web site css link redirect

Tags: css

in my web page there is a read more option the read more option is redirecting about us page. when click on read more the about us page opening, i want that link redirect in bottom of about us page not top. how can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question but I think what you want is this:

Change the Read More link to

```
<a href="about.html#bottom">Read More</a>
```

Then add an anchor to the About Us page:

```
<h1>Top section</h1>
<p>Some info</p>    
<p>Some info</p>
<a name="bottom">
    <h1>Bottom section</h1>
</a>
<p>More info</p>
<p>More info</p>
```